# ngx-image-cropper , roundCropper = "true" not working , its showing this error - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: angular, ngx-image-cropper

```
<image-cropper [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent" [maintainAspectRatio]="true" [aspectRatio]="4 / 4"
    format="jpg" (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)" roundCropper = "true">
</image-cropper>
```

[screenshot attached for your reference][image]

I used `roundCropper = "True"`. But its not working and throwing the error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

If a try to run the same code on stackblitz then its working. I have also tried it with `roundCropper = true` , but its giving same error.

I want to use round cropper in my ngx-image-cropper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to surround roundCropper with []
[roundCropper] = "true"